# Launch a controller from within an active story board

Tags: iphone, ios5, uistoryboard

I have a pretty basic app flow that is quite linear, so it fits in with the storyboard quite well. However there is one requirement that I am not sure on how to achieve. Structurally the app flow looks like this.

1. Table View Controller (Master)
2. Static Table View Controller (Detail, bound to a core data model)
3. Launches a modal web view. (uses a delegate for callbacks)

Now the requirement is that one of the options on the detail is to set the item as "default".
Then if one were to suspend the app and go to the settings app and enable an "auto launch" option, then when resuming the app it should launch the modal web view directly, when dismissed the user is to be returned to the Table View Controller in #1.

Initially I was going to terminate the app if the auto launch was enabled, however I have since read that this practice is frowned upon.

So my confusion is, the user could be at any stage through the storyboard, then suspends the app, enables the auto launch from the settings then resumes the app, how do you "reset" your story board. Or are there any built in mechanisms to handle this?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a clause, that you run different segues according to if Auto Launch enabled or not. And make more complex Storyboard with two segues for these two options.

Comment: I understand this approach for the app launch scenario. But where I am confused is from the resume scenario, where the app could be in some unknown state along the storyboard. Is there some way to reset it or something? Bit new to all of this.